# Getting cropped images when i download amchart graph

Tags: angularjs, pdf-generation, amcharts

have this problem, not everytime, but 1/10 of the downloads the graph gets downloaded partially, i get only the top left part
the code I'm using to convert the graph to png it's the following:

```
var chart = AmCharts.charts[AmCharts.charts.length-1]  
chart.export.capture( {}, 
function() { this.toPNG( { multiplier: 2,  },
 function( data ) { pdf_layout.images[ "image_" + chart.id ] = data; 
this.download(data, 'test.png') } ); } );
```

I'm using AmCharts 3 if this can help
I tried to use the most recent library of amcharts export, but nothing seems to fix it
I have the export attribute set to active in my json chart